# No Man's Sky: How the “colored placement” bonus to upgrades (in Exosuit / Multi-tool / Starship) works?

Tags: no-mans-sky

There is an idea that (from [nomanssky.gamepedia.com](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com)):

> If upgrade items of the same type are placed adjacent to each other, they may provide different bonuses. If a bonus is awarded, the player will be notified of this effect with a colored light linking the relevant upgrades.

So:

- How does it work? / What is mechanics behind it?
- Do the bonuses stack up? E.g., whether two in one place and two in another give the similar bonus than four next to each other?
- Should the updates be placed next to its related tool? E.g., “Beam Focuses” next to “Mining Beam”. Will it give the greater bonus?
- How to update Jetpack if it is in the corner? “Jetpack Boosters” next to each other are highlighted with yellow.

Comment: From my experience of adding upgrades randomly at first and later after hearing this theory I can say I personally don't see any difference. My mining doesn't feel faster, my gun doesn't have more ammo or deal more damage. Grouping them together adds the colored border but I can't see what else it does.

Comment: @Virusbomb, yeah I feel the same. Looks like that color border should notify user about something, but looks like no one really understands how it works. I have only found vague mentioning about _some_ bonuses it _may_ provide.